# How to use mutliple colors in same cell in excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

I need to use multiple colors in one excel cell but the code below works only last condition.

[image: show image]

I want like: grren-red-green-red-green-red

It works like: green-green-green-green-green-red

```
        List<string> myTexts = new List<string>
        {
            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",  // green expected
            "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",  // red expected
            "ccccccccccccccccc",  // green expected
            "ddddddddddddddddd",  // red expected
            "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",  // green expected
            "fffffffffffffffff"   // red expected
        };


        var startIndex = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++)
        {
            cell.Value2 += myTexts[i];

            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                cell.Characters(startIndex, myTexts[i].Length).Font.Color= Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Characters(startIndex, myTexts[i].Length).Font.Color = Color.Red;
            }

            startIndex += myTexts[i].Length;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

it should work if you set the cell.value2 text outside the loop to the complete string and manipulate the style afterwards:

```
        cell.Value2 = string.Join("", myTexts);
        var startIndex = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < myTexts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                cell.Characters[startIndex, myTexts[i].Length].Font.Color = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.Characters[startIndex, myTexts[i].Length].Font.Color = Color.Red;
            }

            startIndex += myTexts[i].Length;
        }
```

Comment: Marinus first thanks for your response . Actually your code works if cell.Value2 has no string value However i have a string value in cell like xxxxxxxxx . After i start to add into cell first element of list it takes its color . For example xxxxxxx value is color of blue  before the first element was added. After insert it shows green . I dont want to do that . How can i disable this ? It is the main problem for me .

Comment: you can read the old colors, change the text and apply the formatting again: https://gist.github.com/BlackEspresso/75638a7e7c090293b65fc7d42b72ddba